# In java selenium i am trying to send backspace character ('\uE003') or (\u0008) to a textbox to clear existing text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
textboxElement.sendKeys("\uE003");
(or)
textboxElement.sendKeys("\u0008");
```

But instead of removing the existing text in the textbox,   003 or 0008 is getting  added to the textbox. i cant use `Keys.BACK_SPACE` because it is not working on Ubuntu server.

Comment: try using .clear() method.

Comment: Is there an overload of `sendKeys` that accepts a `char` as an argument so you can pass `'\u0008'`?

Comment: when java accepts the '\ue003' as part of input string it is stripping of '\u' and only sending '003' text to input textbox, so handle this we need to tell not to escape like below
  textboxElement.sendKeys(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\uE003"));

Answer (score 1):

Try applying the usual control a, then delete. This will clear the whole text in a textfield.

```
textboxElement.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
textboxElement.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) first import selenium Keys to your class

(2) best way to clean/clear any input field through using length ,below method will delete/backspace 
the all character in dynamic manner:

```
public void clearText(WebDriver driver, WebElement element)
{
        String areaText = element.getText();
        int  lengthOfString = text.length();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < lengthOfString ; i++)
        {
            element.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE);
        }
}

or we can use below:

element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
element.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);

or 

element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
element.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```